# 2D Heatmap using python for already binned data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to obtain a 2D Heatmap (using python) for a dataset that is already binned such that I have left and right edges for x and y and then the data I am interested (that I would like colormapped) as a function of x and y.

**I give an example below of what my dataset looks like:**

| x_min | x_max | y_min | y_max | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0.1 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0.1 | 13 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 0.1 | 12 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 0.1 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 9 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 17 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 22 |
| 4 | 5 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 30 |

I would like to plot a 2D Heatmap like this below:
[2D Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCP95.png)

How would that be possible so that I get a heat map that would have for **Y axis** from 0 to 0.2 and for **X axis** from 1 to 5, and a colorbar dependent on 'data'?

Thank you!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html or https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Answer (score 1):

`plt.imshow()` could be used as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''
x_min   x_max   y_min   y_max   Data
1   2   0   0.1 10
2   3   0   0.1 13
3   4   0   0.1 12
4   5   0   0.1 20
1   2   0.1 0.2 9
2   3   0.1 0.2 17
3   4   0.1 0.2 22
4   5   0.1 0.2 30'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)

plt.imshow(df['Data'].to_numpy().reshape(2, 4), origin='lower', extent=[1, 5, 0, 0.2], aspect='auto', cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(range(1, 6))
plt.yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2])
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    plt.text((row.x_min + row.x_max) / 2, (row.y_min + row.y_max) / 2, f"{row.Data:.0f}",
             color='navy' if row.Data > 22 else 'yellow', size=20, ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: example heatmap]